# How prove $\frac{n^3-1}{mn-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

let $m,n$ be positive  integers $(m\ge n\ge 2)$ such that $$\dfrac{n^3-1}{mn-1}$$ is an integer.

show that
$$\dfrac{n^3-1}{mn-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$$
This problem is from this Ivan Loh solve this  problem: [How find all ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such $\frac{n^3-1}{mn-1}$ is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730149/how-find-all-ordered-pairs-m-n-such-fracn3-1mn-1-is-an-integer,But) I can't understand  this step why?can you someone explain more detailed?Thank you

Comment: @Alyosha: No, you would get $n^{3}-1 = (kn+1)(mn-1),$ and both sides are congruent to $-1$ (mod $n$) which is no contradiction.

Comment: @CalvinLin To be fair, I made that comment before the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\frac {n^3-1}{mn-1} \equiv \frac {-1}{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!+1

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $$\dfrac{n^3-1}{mn-1}- 1 =\dfrac{n(n^2-m)}{mn-1} \in \mathbb Z$$

Therefore $mn-1|n(n^2-m)$. Now use the fact that $mn-1$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

**Added** Since $mn-1$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and $mn-1|n(n^2-m)$ it follows that $mn-1|n^2-m$. Therefore,

$$\dfrac{n^3-1}{mn-1}- 1 =n\dfrac{n^2-m}{mn-1} \, \mbox{and} \dfrac{n^2-m}{mn-1} \in \mathbb Z$$

Therefore, by the definition of modular arithmetic,

$$\dfrac{n^3-1}{mn-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

Comment: @CalvinLin Done ;)

Comment: Ah thanks. I should go back to sleep :)

Comment: @CalvinLin I like your proof more, but a short comment: when using properties of modular arithmetic, I would use inverses instead of fractions: $$\frac {n^3-1}{mn-1} \equiv (n^3-1)(mn-1)^{-1} \equiv (-1)(-1)^{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

Comment: Agreed, by right is should check that those inversely exist.

Comment: It's nice! Thank you +1